# React rerender component using hooks when property in an array of object changes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

So I am in a situation where I have to change a particular property from an array of objects. When the property changes I want to rerender the component. Now, this works fine without any issues when use the `setPropertyName` of `useState`. But now I am just changing one property of the object instead of the entire object.

Here is the code that Im working on:

```
const [movieList, setMovieList] = useState([]);
```

Calling the setMovieList and passing an array will obviously cause a rerender.

Consider the following contents of movieList:

```
movieList = [
{
'name': 'Mulholland Dr.'
'year':2001,
'watched' : true,
'rating':0
},
{
'name': 'Zodiac'
'year':2007,
'watched' : false,
'rating':0
},
{
'name': 'Twin Peaks'
'year':2017,
'watched' : true,
'rating': 0
}]
```

Then I have a function which renders the list:

```
function showMovieList () {
    return movieList.map((movie) => {
        return (
            <List.Item key={movie.imdbID}>

                <div className="watchedCheckBoxContainer">
                <input type="checkbox" onChange={(event) => movie.watched = event.target.checked} id={`cb1${movie.imdbID}`}/>
                <label htmlFor={`cb1${movie.imdbID}`}><Image size='tiny' src={movie.Poster} /></label>
                </div>
                {/* <Image size='tiny' src={movie.Poster} /> */}

                <List.Content>{movie.Title}</List.Content>
                {movie.watched ? <Rating maxRating={5} onRate={(event, {rating}) => movie.userRating=rating}/> : null}


            </List.Item>
        )
    });
}
```

As you can see , when the checkbox is clicked it changes the value of the watched property. A few lines later I'm checking if `movie.watched == true` then show the `<Rating>` component. But in this case, I'm not using setMoviesList to update the moviesList and hence the `<Rating>` component is not visible.

How can I use `setMoviesList` to update watched property of the particular movie whose checkbox I click on?

Comment: Have an id in the list and update the list with response of matching id.

Comment: Yeah. That was going to be my ultimate solution. Thought there was some other way to update it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay.. I solved it by the following way:

```
function onMovieWatched (watched, index) {
    const tempMoviesList = [...movieList];
    tempMoviesList[index].watched = watched;
    setMovieList(tempMoviesList);
}

<input type="checkbox" onChange={(event) => onMovieWatched(event.target.checked, idx)} id={`cb1${movie.imdbID}`}/>
```

The `idx` is the index that I am using from the map method.
Initially I was afraid that I might have to loop over the entire array and get the object that matches the imdbID and then update its property.

Luckily I have the index while mapping over it, so I just used that to directly retrieve the object.

Dont know why I didnt think of this solution before posting.